# How to create an object from a variable value inside a class

Tags: php

I need to write a method with a variable passed to it which contains the class name. With this variables value (class name) that method should create an object and return it.

It looks like this:

```
public function middleware($name)
{
    require_once("../Middlewares/$name.php");

    $construct = new \Middlewares\$name;

    return $construct;
}
```

Since classes inside Middlewares folder are using namespace Middlewares and the namespace inside the class from which I'm trying to call an object is something different I should use \Middlewares\ prefix but PHP won't accept the variable in there and says:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$name' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in D:\xampp\htdocs\Bootstrap\Middleware.class.php on line 11

What is the proper syntax to make it right? Or any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build it in a variable:

```
    $class = '\Middlewares\\' . $name;
    $construct = new $class;
```

Or:

```
    $class = "\\Middlewares\\$name";
    $construct = new $class;
```